# Can we SELECT ONE FROM (a table) WHERE we have multiple rows of same column names?

Tags: php

I have table (table1) it has two columns (column1 & column2) and two rows of some values. Say row#1 got (hi , hello) and row#2 got (hi , hey).

Now i usually use this `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = hi`
But since i have two rows of same values, can we call one instead of both.(irrespective of random pick)

NOTE:: Here i dont know second value of row so, cant use it as a bait.

Any help is Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = hi LIMIT 1
```

Use LIMIT 1 to select one record, together with ORDER BY i think you can achieve what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = hi LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```